# Can I use Laravel and Ionic with the same database?

Tags: android, ios, laravel, ionic-framework

I have a few questions about Laravel and Ionic.

1. Can I use the same database with a Laravel project and an Ionic project? If yes, what type of database can I use MySQL, PostgreSQL, MongoDB, Firebase)?
2. Can I make a website with Ionic (and convert the website to apps, too)?

Answer (score 0):

Database is server side while ionic is a front-end framework. So they are not related.
The basic is as follow: you retrieve data from database by your back-end services (laravel), you change the data according to your design and you send them to the front-end (ionic) with json format. The database is not that important and you can pick which one you are comfortable with.
And as for your second question, ionic is a framework to build apps. But since it uses Angular it can be used for website, but it is not practical.

Comment: Note Ionic support the 'browser' platform.

Comment: I just need to make everything clear in my mind , so for example I create a website with laravel with mysql database and with ionic I display this data

Comment: @JoeriShoeby You are right I totally forgot about that.

Comment: @IhAbMouDhich Actually it's a JSON API that you're creating. Laravel returns JSON to your Ionic application. Only when you're return views (html) with Laravel you are building a website. Laravel supports both.